# Three-way energy harnessing device engineering

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

I have a question regarding a certain engineering of a such device capable of harnessing energy in such three way. So, what I want to happen is to implement a solar and motion energy harnessing. The concept is that, this device can harness the sun's solar energy, but the solar panel is designed in a way that it can capture rain drops. basically, this solar panel can act as a roof, then it is slanted and funneled through a wheel system that is designed to be push by the water collected by the solar roof. Furthermore, this device also harnesses the power of wind that it is engineered in such way that it dynamically reverts it self toward the air direction. All of this energy is stored in a one energy container.

Anyways, my greatest apologies if my explanation and grammar is so bad. I hope that you understood my concept at least. I am open to every answer, it is due to finding out whether this idea is delusional or if it is actually possible. Thank you very much for answer.

Comment: There is literally no question here.  In English, a question is designated by a question mark.

Comment: Welcome to E.SE, William. The SE sites are Question & Answer sites, not the usual discussion forum. You need to ask a question that we can answer. There is an [Edit] link below your question. (Otherwise it will be closed as "needing more focus".) If it is any help, you can forget about trying to generate significant energy from rainfall on something the size and height of the roof of a house. The optimum solution will be to make a good photo-electric system and a good wind energy system. Combine the two by connecting them to the grid or to a common battery.